# Dynamically created popups not opened by links

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, asynchronous

I'm filling up a listview with items out of localStorage.
A click on a list item should open up the respective popup.
I have an existing solution that works just like that, served completely on request though.
This time I'm adding the markup for the popups and items on the fly and thus need to initialize these manually.

What I observed is, that the popups themselves are initialized properly (can be shown via .popup( 'open' ) ) and it is merely a problem of the trigger links of each popup doing nothing.
jQm seems to ignore the trigger links and yet it initializes the popups just fine.

I've tried the following after filling in the html for each item:

```
this.$el.trigger( 'create' );
this.$el.find( '[data-role="popup"]' ).popup();
$.mobile.activePage.trigger( 'create' );
this.$el.trigger( 'create' );
```

While the popups seem to be set up just fine, I can't get them get triggered by the links, like they should be.

A trigger link looks like this in my code:

```
<a href="#<%- popupId %>" data-rel="popup" data-transition="slideup" data-position-to="window">
```

Is there anything I need to do for jQm to fetch these too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the reference: I fixed this by triggering the 'create' event on the parent list, not on the respective anchors.

While this is contrary to the docs, it seems to be quite an individual issue as it worked the other way around in another, similar situation on another codebase.
I won't go into details over this though, it works as long as it works.